# SpringBoot JPA Repository - get selected fields shows error "Column not found"

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

#### I want to **fetch selected columns**, preferably dynamically.

For now, I'm specifying static columns - id, title, description.

**Category.java**

```
@Entity(name="Category")
@Table(name="categories")
public class Category {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private long id;
   private String slug;
   private String title;
   private String description;
   private String preview_image;
   private int isFeatured;

   /*  Getters, setters etc */
}
```

**CategoryRepository.java**

```
public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Category, Long> {

    @Query(
        value = "SELECT id, title, description FROM categories", 
        nativeQuery = true
    )
    List<Category> findAll();
}
```

This gives the error:

> Column 'is_featured' not found. Exception class: class
>   org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException
>   Exception [could not execute query; SQL [SELECT id, title, description
>   FROM categories]; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query]

Any idea how this error can be resolved? I was thinking of using another model instead of **Category** but I need to make the fields dynamic later on. It's hard to make model class if I'm unaware of which fields to return.

Also, is there a way I can make this `@Query` code dynamic such that it returns columns mentioned in parameter?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Add @Repository to CategoryRepository interface

Comment: Still showing the same errors

Comment: As metioned by Patrick, you need to add Column annotation on isFeatured field. For dynamic columns, it is not supported in Query annotation. But have a look the this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47407043/spring-data-jpa-pass-column-name-and-value-as-parameters) for some suggested solutions.

Comment: Does the answer help or do you have any other issue?

Answer (score 0):

Its because of the naming strategy of Spring and Hibernate. It will convert `camelCase` to `SNAKE_CASE` by default. So in your case its `isFeatured` -> `is_featured`.

If you dont want to change the naming strategy just add `@Column("isFeatured")` on your property. This will override the default behavior of this property.

Here you can find more [Spring Boot + JPA : Column name annotation ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25283198/3493036)

Regarding dynamic query. You should look up the features in the documentation of Spring-data-jpa and about `querydsl`